# curve_fit from scipy generates wrong values

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have several data from measurements, and I wanted to fit my own function onto this data. For that I wanted to use `curve_fit`. Therefore I implemented it in the following way:

```
def func(self, w, H, T, L):
    B = (L + 0.25)*((2 * math.pi / T)** 4)
    S = (B**L)*H*H / (4 * scipy.special.gamma(L)*(w**( 4 * L + 1)))*numpy.exp(-B / (w*w*w*w))
    return S

def fit_this(self):
    self.popt, self.copt = curve_fit(self.func, self.xdata, self.ydata)
    print self.popt
    print self.copt
```

`self.xdata` and `self.ydata` contain my measured values. I already did the fit with the same function in another program (matlab) and therefore I already know working parameters. But when  start this program, I get for `popt` definitely wrong parameters, and the covariance of the values is somewhere in the range of `10e+22`, and therefore completely useless. Why is that happening (Guess: Wrong starting values), and how can I improve this situation? If providing my data helps I can provide them, too.

Comment: What is `self.multiFit`?

Comment: since you already guessed that bad initial values could be the reason: have you tried using better initial values?

Comment: @aganders3: Sorry, that was another try, corrected it in the op

Comment: Yes, that works, but is there a way to get better initial values than simply via trial and error?